# Lighthouse report says my start_url isnt cached

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json, lighthouse

Having run a Lighthouse report on my budding PWA, the report tells me that:

> User will not be prompted to Install the Web App Failures:
>   Manifest start_url is not cached by a Service Worker.

But it is! I can SEE it in the cache in the "Application" tab on Chrome's F12 tools

[image]

I can confirm that the entry in the manifest.json is correct too as the "App Manifest" area in F12 tools shows this

[image]

I have tried changing it to work with just a basic HTML only page and get the same issue in the report. I have also tried changing the URL to just / but no change in the Lighthouse report.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm getting a "Failure: Service worker does not successfully serve the manifest's start_url". Beating my head against a wall... I've read some stuff that hints that it is because my start_url doesn't match to any of the service-worker cached URLs

Comment: If you have included the start url in your cached urls (in the service worker) and are still getting that error, check that there arent any OTHER service worker errors, as service worker errors tend to affect each other

Comment: There appears to be no other errors - I feel like I've tried everything. This sucks because it tells me that "users will not be prompted to install site" or w/e - which is the main benefit of PWA.

Comment: I suggest you post a new question with details of the contents of your service worker JS, manifest.json and start_url page html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to a "buggy" Lighthouse. Its being constantly updated and improved and no longer reports my start_url as being problematic.

Another issue I came across that was driving me mental was Lighthouse reporting that the site was using HTTP/1.1 (with no compression) when various online resources were showing me it was using HTTP/2 (with compression) (IIS 10 automatically serves HTTP/2 if client supports it) It turns out that my antivirus was messing with HTTPS traffic - soon as I turned off HTTPS threat detection, Lighthouse was reporting HTTP/2 with compression.

[image]

Comment: I'm still having this issue in Chrome 67.0.3396.79. It works in Chrome Canary 69.0.3455.0. I get no prompts to install the PWA but if I choose "Add to home screen" in iOS Safari it does install the PWA properly (I see no browser chrome)